# Use stream API to return a certain number of enum values

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

Using the stream API in Java 8, `createObjects()` below will return a list of `X` objects in a one-liner.

```
public class StreamObjectCreator {

    public List<X> createObjects(Integer... s) {
        return Arrays.stream(s).map(X::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static class X {
        int s;
        public X(int s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, consider the below enum `Y`:

```
private static enum Y {

    VALUE_1(2), VALUE_2(1);

    private int i;

    private Y(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

}
```

I would like to do something similar and return the following list:

> [VALUE_1, VALUE_1, VALUE_2]

In other words, `i` occurrences of each enum value.

Using the "old" Java way, it can be implemented like this.

```
List<Y> createEnumList() {
    List<Y> list = new ArrayList<Y>();
    for (Y y : Y.values()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y.getI(); i++) {
            list.add(y);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Can this be done with less boilerplate code using the stream API or some lambda expression? I played around with the stream API for a while without success, and most information found on Google points to "easier" tutorials.

Comment: I don’t get the purpose of this code…

Comment: You can do it with streams, yes, but not in "less code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always do

```
List<Y> createEnumList() {
    return Stream.of(Y.values())
                 .flatMap(y -> IntStream.range(0, y.getI()).mapToObj(i -> y))
                 .collect(toList());
}
```

although your requirement is a bit weird.

`Stream.of` will create a `Stream<Y>` from which you map each Y instance to a Stream that contains this instance n times, n being the `getId()` value. This `Stream<Stream<Y>>` is then flatten so that you get back a `Stream<Y>`.

Finally, you collect the pipeline's content in a List.

Comment: I understand it might seem wierd, but it is what I want to do. By the way, your code returns `List<Object>`, unless I imported the wrong `toList()` method.

Comment: @Magnilex It's a static import of `java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;`. It should return a `List<Y>` as expected (I've tested it with IntelliJ maybe you are using Eclipse and its buggy Java 8 compiler).

Comment: You are correct. I actually found Eclispe having quite nice Java 8 support nowadays, but this was a bummer. Another case where IDEA wins.

Answer (score 7):

I can’t imagine a real use case but

```
List<Y> createEnumList() {
    return EnumSet.allOf(Y.class).stream()
        .flatMap(y->Collections.nCopies(y.getI(), y).stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
return Stream.of(Y.values())
             .flatMap(y -> Stream.generate(() -> y).limit(y.getI()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

but it's a matter of opinion whether this is any more readable than the "old-style" way...

```
Stream.generate(() -> y).limit(y.getI())
```

creates a potentially-infinite stream of `y` values, then truncates it after `i` repetitions.